# A pyparsing grammar for parsing titles containing 'v.'

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am thinking about parsing titles of the form

```
<left part> v. <right part>
```

by using `pyparsing`. The left part can be names with alphanumeric characters including utf-8 characters and punctuation. Even `v.` itself is allowed in the left part. However the `v.` in the middle is always separated from the two parts, by spaces.

Can a grammar be defined for this situation?

An effort that I made:

```
name = Word(alphas)
part1 = OneOrMore(name).setParseAction(lambda tokens:" ".join(tokens))
part2 = OneOrMore(name)
v_en = Word("v.").suppress()
v_fr = Word("c.").suppress()
versus = v_en 

expression = part +  versus + part2
```

is not working very well because punctuation is allowed in the left part (and only works until the first dot)

Answer (score 2):

Are you married to the idea of using pyparsing? Because if you aren't, then you can quickly solve your problem using python built-in features, with the following assumption:

' v. ' does not occur in

For a given title, try:

```
>>> pattern = ' v. '
>>> title.rsplit(pattern, 1)
```

E.g.,

```
>>> 'this is a v. simple test'.rsplit(pattern, 1)
['this is a', 'simple test']
>>> 'A more v. complicated v. example'.rsplit(pattern, 1)
['A more v. complicated', 'example']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just posting two team names separated by "v.", as in "Univ. of Calif. v. Univ. of Notre Dame", then you can parse that a couple of different ways.

One way that *doesn't* work is using `Word` as you have in your post. `Word` is intended to specify not a specific literal word, but a word-group made up of characters in a particular string. For instance, if you were trying parse acronyms that were words in all caps, then you would define that as:

```
acronym = Word(alphas.upper())
```

and this would match "GE", "IBM", "CIA", "FBI", etc.

`Word("blah")` would match "bah", "hal", "bbba", "hhhbbll" - any word group made up of the letters "b", "l", "a", or "h".  In your post, `Word("v.")` would match "vvvv", "....", "v.v.v.v." - any adjacent group containing v's and .'s. To define the literal "v.", you really are thinking of `Literal` or `Keyword` instead.

`Keyword` is really the most appropriate solution, I think. The purpose of `Keyword` over `Literal` is that `Keyword` adds the constraint that the parsed characters contain only the given literal, and cannot have any other common word characters adjacent. So `Literal("who")` would match the leading part of "whoever", but `Keyword("who")` would not.

So to parse that sample text, the simplest is to use `SkipTo`:

```
from pyparsing import Keyword, SkipTo, restOfLine
test = "Univ. of Calif. v. Univ. of Notre Dame"
vs = Keyword("v.")

matchup = SkipTo(vs)("team1") + vs + restOfLine("team2")

print matchup.parseString(test).dump()
```

If you want to be more specific about your teams, and might try something like this:

```
from pyparsing import Keyword, Combine, OneOrMore, Word, alphas
vs = Keyword("v.")
teamWord = Word(alphas+".")
teamName = Combine(OneOrMore(teamWord), " ", adjacent=False)
matchup = teamName("team1") + vs + teamName("team2")

print matchup.parseString(test).dump()
```

But this will give you this exception

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "v." (at char 38), (line:1, col:39)
```

As it is now, the separating "v." matches as a valid team word. You need to include a negative lookahead before building up a team word, so that "v." does not get mistaken for one.

```
teamWord = ~vs + Word(alphas+".")
```

Will print out:

```
['Univ. of Calif.', 'v.', 'Univ. of Notre Dame']
- team1: Univ. of Calif.
- team2: Univ. of Notre Dame
```

Comment: Hi @Paul McGuire Thanks for taking the time to answer. Brilliant answer! I am having a further question though. Suppose the we have something like `P.S.V. Eidhoven v. Ajax`. In other words I cannot prevent `v.` from occurring inside team initials but I can guarantee that in order for the two sides to be separated, `v.` surrounded with spaces, has to occur in the middle

Comment: Try `vs = White() + Keyword("v.") + White()` I don't usually encourage people to explicitly include whitespace in their grammars, but there may not be any way around it in this case. If you do this, you can probably remove the negative lookahead in `teamword`, too (since a `teamword` can't possibly start with whitespace).